# The meaning of the word “bums”

Tags: word-meaning

The quotation below is from Peter Benchley’s Jaws:

“…; the homeowners complained that bums were littering the beaches or disturbing the peace;”

I would like to know the meaning of “bums” in this context. Among its many senses I have found in dictionary, I couldn’t know which one to choose as the most appropriate for this particular context.

Comment: Are you reading a paper copy of the novel? It looks like a typo. "Bums" would make more sense.  Or can you supply more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context "bums" refers to indigents or homeless persons. That would be meanings 1 and 2 from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bums):

> **bum** (*n.*)
>
> 1) a disreputable loafer or idler
>    2) a tramp; hobo
>    3) an irresponsible,
>       unpleasant, or mean person